# How to use audioWorklet.addModule in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I have started trying to create an audio recorder to use in React using the [Web Audio API](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audioapi)

Here is the code for my Recorder class

```
import AudioNode from './workletNode'


export default class Recorder {
  constructor(context) {

    this.context = context
    this.recording = false

    console.log(context)

    context.audioWorklet.addModule('processor.js')
      .then(() => {
        console.log('added worklet module')

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
          .then(stream => {
            console.log('Have stream')
            let microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
            let wavEncoder = new AudioNode(context)

            microphone.connect(wavEncoder).connect(context.destination)
          })
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert('Error getting audio')
        console.log(e)
      })
  }


  record() {
    console.log('Start recorder')
    this.recording = true
  }

  stop() {
    console.log('Stop recorder')
    this.recording = false
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is with this line:  `context.audioWorklet.addModule('processor.js')`

the processor.js file doesn't get added.

and then an error is thrown when it gets to this line:

```
let wavEncoder = new AudioNode(context)
```

The error is:

*Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__workletNode___default.a is not a constructor*

I've tried the same code outside of react and it is fine. So it is something to do with using `audioWorklet.addModule` inside react.

Can anyone help?

This is the react component that calls recorder:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Button} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl'
import Recorder from './recorder'

class SpeechToTextAudioWorklet extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.context = null
    this.recorder = null
  }

  startRecorder() {
    if (!this.context) {
      this.context = new window.AudioContext()
      this.recorder = new Recorder(this.context)
    } else {
      this.context.resume()
    }

    this.recorder && this.recorder.record()
  }

  stopRecorder() {
    this.recorder && this.recorder.stop()
  }

  render() {

    return (<div>Speech to text

      <Button id="start" onClick={() => {
        this.startRecorder()
      }}>Record</Button>
      <Button id="stop" onClick={() => {
        this.stopRecorder()
      }}>Stop</Button>
      <div id="recordingslist"></div>
    </div>)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {}
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(injectIntl(SpeechToTextAudioWorklet))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try making a `worklet` directory inside the `public` folder, move your AudioWorkletProcesser there, and change your code to reflect the new path: `context.audioWorklet.addModule('worklet/processor.js')`.